# How do I deploy a full stack application?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, backend, hosting

I built a simple portfolio website with a golang backend with one rest api endpoint for my contact form. It sends an email to me.
I got my frontend deployed but wonder how I can connect it to the backend on my domain. The backend is this simple program:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/smtp"

    "github.com/rs/cors"
)

type EmailRequest struct {
    SenderEmail string `json:"senderEmail"`
    SenderName  string `json:"senderName"`
    Message     string `json:"message"`
}

func SendEmail(emailReq EmailRequest) error {
    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", "myemail@gmail.com", "***", "smtp.gmail.com")
    msg := fmt.Sprintf("From:\r%s\nName:\r%s\nMessage:\r%s\n", emailReq.SenderEmail, emailReq.SenderName, emailReq.Message)
    err := smtp.SendMail("smtp.gmail.com:587", auth, "email@gmail.com", []string{"myemail@gmail.com"}, []byte(msg))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func Email(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != "POST" {
        w.Header().Set("Allow", "POST")
        w.WriteHeader(405)
        w.Write([]byte("Method Not Allowed"))
        return
    }
    var emailReq EmailRequest
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&emailReq); err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        w.Write([]byte("Bad Request"))
        return
    }
    if err := SendEmail(emailReq); err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        w.Write([]byte("Internal Server Error"))
        log.Printf("Error with the SendEmail func execution: %v", err)
        return
    }
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write([]byte("Email sent successfully"))
}

func main() {
    c := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins:   []string{"http://exampledomain.com"},
        AllowedMethods:   []string{http.MethodPost},
        AllowCredentials: true,
    })
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/email/", Email)

    handler := c.Handler(mux)

    log.Print("Listening on port :8080")
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handler)
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

and the frontend is a simple React application.

I uploaded the frontend by running npm run build and making a zip file out of the build folder. Now I wonder how I can upload the backend folder to the domain.

Comment: Where are you hosting the front end?  Which provider and service?

Comment: I'm hosting on godaddy.com and my domain is also bought from there.

Comment: So you will need to find a place that offers "compute power" and supports running Golang.  One option you might consider is looking at Firebase Hosting + Firebase Cloud Functions (that [support Golang](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup/#go) ).